# cant make marquee in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, marquee

I'm trying to use marquee effect on the listitems of a recyclerview but it does not work even though i type `holder.view.setSelected(true);` and    `android:ellipsize="marquee"`

```
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
```

in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Im trying to use marquee effect on the listitems of a recyclerview but it does not work even though" />
```

[image]

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle
compile ‘com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0’
Create adapter for RecyclerView
Create adapter for RecyclerView. If you don’t know how to create an adapter, please follow the link.
Make horizontal scroll
For RecyclerView, we have to use LayoutManager. There is a method, which is stated below.

1. LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
2. linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
   Use this in RecyclerView, stated below.
3. yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager );
   Your RecyclerView will be scrolled horizontally.
   Creating auto scroll for RecyclerView
   I want to make a list, which will auto scroll like a news feed. Hence, I use a thread auto scroll. There is a method in RecyclerView, which is smoothScrollToPosition(), as it takes the position for the scroll’s present position to the desired position. The counter is incremented when all the items are incremented and counter is started from the beginning.
4. Here, I use a thread, which will perform autoscroll for the items of RecyclerView. There is a method in RecyclerView, which is smoothScrollToPosition(), which takes the position of recyclerview to scroll the position to current position. Hence, I use a thread to increment the position automatically, so an autoscroll is happening because the position is incremented automatically. When all the incremented positions are equal to the total item size, start from the beginning. In this way, an autoscroll effect has happened.
   Here, the code is mentioned below.

```java
 public void autoScroll()
 {
    final int speedScroll = 0;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable = new Runnable()
  {
    int count =0;
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      if(count== scrollStockAdapter.getItemCount())
      count =0;
      if(count<scrollStockAdater.getItemCount())
      {
        rec_scroll_stock.smoothScrollPosition(++count);
      }
    }
  };
  handler.postDelayed(ruunable,speedScroll);
}
```

```
     LinearLayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this)
    { @Override
     public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView    recyclerview, RecycleView.State state, int position)
     {LinearSmoothScroller smoothscroller = new  LinearSmoothScroller(MainActivity.this)
       {private static final float SPEED = 4000f; //default 25f
         @Override
           protected float calculatedSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics  displaymetrics)
            {
              return SPEED/displaymetrics.densityDpi;
            }
       };
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroller(smoothScroller);
        }
      }
```

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
android : id="@+id/rec_all_stocks" 
android : layout_width="match_parent" 
android : layout_height="match_parent" 
android: scrollbars="vertical"
android : layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android : layout_alignParentStart = "true" 
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Create Smooth scroll automatically
Now, the main problem is auto scroll speed, which is too fast. For RecyclerView, we have to declare a LayoutManager. In LayoutManager, there is a method, which is smoothScrollToPosition(), which is responsible for smooth scrolling. For scrolling, there is a velocity, where the default speed is 25f. To change this velocity, you have to override this method. If you want a smooth scroll, increase this value as you want. In my case, I use 4000f.